# Why Turtlebot3_navigation2 launch file different from Github

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros2 foxy in ubuntu 20.04
when I check the turtlebot3_navigation2 launch file by typing command

```
vi /opt/ros/foxy/share/turtlebot3_navigation2/launch/navigation2.launch.py
```

find this code `PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([nav2_launch_file_dir, '/nav2_bringup_launch.py'])`

was different from github turtlebot3_navigation2 foxy-devel branch

`PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([nav2_launch_file_dir, '/bringup_launch.py'])`

here the link [github turtlebot3_navigation2](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/foxy-devel/turtlebot3_navigation2/launch/navigation2.launch.py)

I have already check my ros version is foxy, and use `sudo apt install ros-foxy-turtlebot3` to install

Is there any way to inspect my  turtlebot3_navigation2 git version in path /opt/ros/foxy/share/turtlebot3_navigation2 ?

Why this problem occur?

Thanks for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367896/why-turtlebot3_navigation2-launch-file-different-from-github/) by [SteveYK](https://answers.ros.org/users/65729/steveyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_foxy_default.html?q=turtlebot3_navigation2 the latest version (as of writing this) is 2.1.0, comparing that with `foxy-devel` using github I see lots of commits (19 at the moment):

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/compare/2.1.0...foxy-devel

Including the commit that changed the line you are referencing:

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/commit/f2209819bb8109cd77f15b903690e12355322732

What this means is that they have committed these changes to `foxy-devel` intending for them to be part of foxy eventually, but they have not done a release for foxy since then and therefore the changes you see on GitHub are not reflected in the latest foxy binaries. If you want to compare what you have from your binary with the source code, use one of these two links:

- 2.1.0 tag on the main repository:

  - https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/tree/2.1.0
- or the release repository (used by our build farm to build packages):

  - https://github.com/robotis-ros2-release/turtlebot3-release/tree/release/foxy/turtlebot3_navigation2

I recommend the first one, but it's possible there are patches included in the second one that aren't the upsteam source. In this case I still recommend the first link.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SteveYK](https://answers.ros.org/users/65729/steveyk/) on 2020-12-20**:
Thanks, I think it solved my problem.